# Set a background image to Listbox item

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, listboxitem

I'm able to set an image to Listbox using the background property.
But how do I set a desirable image as a background to items of the listbox?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm unsure as to what you're asking. are you wanting an Image Item (maybe along with some text) in each ListBoxItem and then want to set those images?

Comment: Sir, I want to do in both the ways. Initially setting an image to the ListBoxItem is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to redefine the ItemTemplate property of the ListBox. If you're not confident with XAML, you should try using Expression Blend.

Here is an example of how you're XAML could look like. I created a new application using the Pivot Template application.

```xaml
        <ListBox x:Name="FirstListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                  <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Height="78">
                    <StackPanel.Background>
                        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/Koala.jpg"/>
                    </StackPanel.Background>
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                  </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

So the default ItemTemplate uses a StackPanel as main container. What you want to do here, is to set the image as the background of that StackPanel. That's what the following lines stands for:

```xaml
                <StackPanel.Background>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/Koala.jpg"/>
                </StackPanel.Background>
```

With the above code, you set an ImageBrush as the Background property of the StackPanel.

With that code, each ListBoxItem will display a koala.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping the listbox item using border and setting the background might help.Follow this sample

```
  <Border Width="380" Height="60" Margin="0,0,0,10" >
       <Border.Background>
          <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/menu_bg.png" />
       </Border.Background>
       <TextBlock  Foreground="Black" FontSize="22" Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
   </Border>
```