# How to apply alternative rows backgrounds in listbox items in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I need to display alternative rows in `ListBox` with different background. My `ListBox` looks like this:

```xml
<ListBox Height="547" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="7,203,0,0" Name="lstboxProducts" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="424" >
    <ListBoxItem>
        <Grid Height="100" Width="420">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="/Images/dark/appbar.magnify.png"/>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                <TextBlock Text="Item heading" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Height="56" />
                <TextBlock Text="item description" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" Height="46" Width="276" />
            </StackPanel>
            <Image Grid.Column="2" Source="/Images/dark/appbar.magnify.png"/>
        </Grid>
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AlternatingRowsConverter : IValueConverter
{
private bool _alternate;

public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
           System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
  _alternate = !_alternate;
  return _alternate
        ? new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0))
        : new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 255));
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
             System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) 
{ throw new NotImplementedException(); }
 }
}
```

Then, listbox template:

```
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"
       x:Name="Mylistbox"
       SelectionChanged="Mylistbox_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
          <Grid Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource alternateConvertor}}">
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                  Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
          </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
```

and finally define the convertor object in the resource dictionary

```
   <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <WindowsPhoneApplication5:AlternatingRowsConverter x:Key="alternateConvertor" />
   </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

[More info here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsphone7series/thread/f9e9ce26-d576-45f8-a79d-762176695385)

Comment: Hi Thanks.Can we apply directly background images to listbox items instead of rgb colors.......?

Comment: you can but I dont know the exact code. This [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10497056/set-a-background-image-to-listbox-item) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you're XAML could look like. I created a new application using the Pivot Template application.

```xml
   <ListBox x:Name="FirstListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Height="78">
                <StackPanel.Background>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/Koala.jpg"/>
                </StackPanel.Background>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
              </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

So the default ItemTemplate uses a StackPanel as main container. What you want to do here, is to set the image as the background of that StackPanel. That's what the following lines stands for:

```xml
<StackPanel.Background>
    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/Koala.jpg"/>
</StackPanel.Background>
```

With the above code, you set an ImageBrush as the Background property of the StackPanel.

With that code, each ListBoxItem will display a koala.